# Add OnGestureListener to Button?

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to add an OnGestureListener or some other way to detect a touch drag across the screen to a button, or some other widget that can be added to a View. I've been trying to figure out how to do this for a while and I can't. I've seen and successfully been able to do it to an activity. Can anyone spell this out for me, because I seem to be having a lot more trouble than I thought I would with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already gone through http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html. The trick is that you can have the `GestureOverlayView` as a transparent layer on top of another `View`. You can then interpret any gestures detected as belonging to the underlying `View`.

In the article, they show you a layout like this:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Any gestures detected could then be interpreted as coming from the ListView. In your case replace the ListView with your Button, and you should be all set.

Comment: This kind of works, but it's causing an issue, because it's automatically eating up the touch event, whether I want it to or not. I need a way that if it isn't a drag operation, it passes the event beyond my gesture view.

Comment: This should do a decent job provided you properly specify the `orientation` and `gestureStrokeType` attributes (as shown above). It HAS to intercept the touch event to detect the gesture, but it SHOULD pass it through if its not accepted as a gesture. Did you include those attributes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be doing dragging and dropping,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: I can't use this in Android 2.2 though or 2.1 could I? That's only in the new 3.0 right?