# Adding gestureoverlayview on top of an existing screen

Tags: android

I am trying to add a gestureoverlayview on top of my existing activity but this is not working.

```
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            tv.setText("Profile "+position);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            ov = (GestureOverlayView)v.findViewById(R.id.overlay);     
            ov.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

I am adding my gestureview like this.It only shows the icon and i am unable to write on the screen.What am i doing wrong?

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                 <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView

    android:id="@+id/overlay" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget44" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_x="201px" android:layout_y="165px" android:gravity="center_horizontal">




        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>






        <TextView android:id="@+id/icon_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textColorHighlight="#656565">
        </TextView>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>


      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your layout: see my answer from [Add OnGestureListener to Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986659/add-ongesturelistener-to-button/5986790#5986790) for detail as to how to do it.

Comment: <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/overlay" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gestureStrokeType="multiple" android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true" android:orientation="vertical"> <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> </ImageView> </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

Comment: The above code only adds the gesture overlay view to the imageview defined.I want to add the gestureoverlayview to the entire screen.

Comment: Well, then you should modify your layout to make the `GestureOverlayView` wrap the entire screen, instead of just the `ImageView`, no? Go ahead and add your entire layout to your question: without it there really isn't a lot of help I can offer.

Comment: Have edited the question though could not enter the entire code  because of some issues on the editor.The entire xml is enclosed in a linear layout.(i have tried putting the textview outside and inside,imageview outside and inside the overlayview.)It still does not encompass the entire screen.

Comment: All good. You should include your linear layout. Put the ENTIRE layout file in place. I expect you haven't set the width/height parameters right.

Comment: i have tried wrap_content,fill_parent.Both of them dont seem to work.It still adds the overlayview(in the above code) only to the textview.

Comment: Well, look at your layout: the only View inside the GestureOverlayView is the text view, so of course that will be the only view that the GestureOverlayView applies to. If you want to have it apply to more than one view, put ALL the views inside the GestureOverlayView. Put a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout inside the GestureOverlayView and then put all other Views inside the LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: Have edited the question once again.Please check if i have wrtten the xml file correctly as it still doen not appear to work and i can only write gestures on the imageview and textview.

Comment: Finally got it working.I had to include the layout of the main view i was using.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help get it off the ground.